# Demonstrate the next propositional excersise( The Constructive Dilema)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How do I solve the next exercise using inference laws, This Rule is also called, "Constructive Dilema"

\begin{align}
p & \rightarrow q \\
-p & \rightarrow -q \\
p & \lor -p \\
\hline \\
q & \lor -q 
\end{align}

Comment: Which inference laws do you have to work with?

Comment: @Bram28 I have to use the basic ones, and basic replacement Modus ponens / Modus tollens
Biconditional introduction / elimination
Conjunction introduction / elimination
Disjunction introduction / elimination
Disjunctive / Hypothetical syllogism Associativity Commutativity Distributivity Double negation De Morgan's laws Transposition Material implication Exportation Tautology Negation introduction

Comment: how is your disjunction elimination defined?

Comment: Do you have conditional introduction, and if so, how is that defined? Also,how is Material implication defined? And finally, what is this 'Tautology' you mention?

Comment: @Bram28   I just need to use the basic rules, Material implication is just p\rightarrow \q \doublearrow -p \lor q  what is called Modus tollens
Biconditional elimination
 / Conjunction elimination / 
Disjunction elimination
 / Disjunctive / Hypothetical syllogism / Associativity/ Commutativity Distributivity /Double negation / De Morgan's laws / Transposition /Negation.

Comment: I still would like to know how disjunction elomination is defined in your system.. Not every system defines it the same way. And again, do you have a conditional introduction rule? And what is this 'Tautology' you mentioned earlier?

Comment: @Bram28 I just need to use the basic rules of clasic logic, if you want to use tautologies you can, the number of solutions increase a lot if all this informations vary??

Comment: If you can use tautologies, then please note that the conclusion $q \lor \neg q$ is a tautology, so it would be a 1 line proof!

Comment: Anyway, you have to understand that there are *many* different systems of logic. So, when you say 'use the basic rules of logic' I really don't know what rules I can use, so you have to let me know how all these rules are ddefined in your system. You gave me the definition for Material Implication before, that's good and helpful. Can you also give me the definitions for some of the others, especially disjunctive elimination, conditional introduction (if you hae that one), and 'Tautology'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49203/discussion-between-juanmunoz-and-bram28).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that just uses the first two premises:

1. $p \rightarrow q$ Premise
2. $\neg p \rightarrow \neg q$ Premise
3. $\neg p \lor q$ Conditional 1
4. $q \lor \neg p$ Commutative 3
5. $\neg \neg q \lor \neg p$ Double Negative 4
6. $\neg q \rightarrow \neg p$ Conditional 5
7. $\neg q \rightarrow \neg q$ Transitivity 2,6
8. $\neg \neg q \lor \neg q$ Conditional 7
9. $q \lor \neg q$ Double Negative 8

And here is a (much simpler!) proof that uses just the third premise:

1. $p \lor \neg p$ Premise
2. $\top$ Negation 1
3. $q \lor \neg q$ Negation 2

Comment: That means that if you dont have the third premise of my question, you still can obtain the answer??

Comment: Correct!  In fact, notice that the third premise is a tautology, so that isn't very useful (a tautology has no information content).

Comment: So our conclusion is too a tautology, and does'nt need premises for being demonstrated????

Comment: Yes, typically when the goal is a tautology, you don't need any premises ... But your system is a little unusual in that it cannot infer anything starting with nothing. So, in this case we did need our premises ... Though probably we could have done it using just 1 premise now that I think about it.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Just noticed that you can do a much simpler proof ... only using premise 3! See my Answer.

Comment: Why Negation 2 gives the result??

Comment: Because the Negation law is an equivalence .. So you can go both ways. Also, you can use it for $p$, $q$, or any statement really